# how to connect users more than number of ports to a single server?

Tags: networking, tcp, client-server, port

According Google the following are the facts on usage of ports:

> The Well Known Ports are those from 0 through 1023. The Registered
>   Ports are those from 1024 through 49151 The Dynamic and/or Private
>   Ports are those from 49152 through 65535

How can i connect more than 65535 users to a single server. because we need to provide a socket to every new listening connection? so wont it create a new port locally for every connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single connection is defined by pair IPserver:server_port and IPclient:client_port. Given that you server_port is just one and is fixed, and your client is defined by IPclient:client_port, it gives a theoretical range of 2^48(32 of IPv4 + 16 of PORT) different clients, so you can have 2^48 parallel connections to a single server.

The limit is that you can't set more than 2^16 connections from a single IP to a single server.

Answer (score 1):

All incoming connections to a listening port use that port. So your problem does not exist, unless you mean you want more than 65535 connections all from the same client host, which would be a strange requirement.

Answer (score -1):

One IP address can only hold a 2 bytes port, as is defined in TCP and UDP protocol. One possible workaround can be like this:

1. server fork n processes, echo listening on 192.168.0.(10+i):9999.(i = 0 to n-1)
2. clients try to connect 192.168.0.10:9999, if fail(192.168.0.10 has no more ports available thus connection cannot be established), then try 192.168.0.11:9999 and so on.

As to how to bind multiple IPs to a single NIC, check this: http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1782-bind-multiple-ips-to-one-nic-in-linux